# No mapping found for HTTP request with uri in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am new to Spring framework. I m trying a very basic example.
Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd    " id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">    
  <display-name>MovieDB</display-name>    
  <servlet>    
    <servlet-name>movie-dispatcher</servlet-name>    
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>    
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
  </servlet>    
  <servlet-mapping>    
    <servlet-name>movie-dispatcher</servlet-name>    
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>    
  </servlet-mapping>    
</web-app>
```

Here is my movie-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd             
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context            
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd    ">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.moviedb.controller" />
    <bean id="viewResolver"      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is my controller

```
package com.moviedb.controller;    
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;    
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;    
@Controller    
public class MovieDBController {        
    @RequestMapping("/homepage")    
    public ModelAndView getHomePage(){    
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("homepage");    
        return model;           
    }       
    @RequestMapping("/movie")    
    public ModelAndView getMovieDetailsPage(){    
        //code              
    }    
}
```

When I type this url in my browser http://localhost:8080/MovieDB/homepage

I'm getting a `404` error and

> org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound WARNING:
>   No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MovieDB/homepage]
>    in DispatcherServlet with name 'movie-dispatcher'

In my server console.

I am not able to figure out what is going wrong here

Comment: Have you tried http://localhost:8080/homepage?

Comment: you need to provice URL pattern as /MovieDB/* for movie dispatcher servlet in your web.xml for your provided url to work. @AleksanderBlomskøld url should work if you dont change your web.xml

Comment: yes but no luck.still the same error .

Answer (score -1):

i think you are missing below line in `movie-dispatcher-servlet.xml` file.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

One more point change url pattern(/) in web.xml to below.

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: can you post your updated movie-dispatcher-servlet.xml(if you have done) file?

Comment: <context-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
 <param-value>/WEB-INF/movie-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
       <listener-class>
          org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
       </listener-class>
  </listener>

Comment: i have just added the listener to the already existing web.xml